# Flutter upgrade(null safety) error | Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

We are trying to upgrade our flutter project to null safety migration using the following link https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.

dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety - Successful
dart pub get - Successful
Migrate your code by hand- https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migrating-by-hand - Successful
dart migrate - Successful

Facing error in the below code while trying to run the flutter command(`Flutter run`)

```
static Future<AppStrings> getAppText(String local) async {
var appTextBox = await Hive.openBox("appTextBox");
AppStrings? appText = new AppStrings(
  mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle'),
  timeText: appTextBox.get('timeText'),
  minutesText: appTextBox.get('minutesText'),
  mainPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageSubtitle'),
  mainPageParagraph: appTextBox.get('mainPageParagraph'),
  mainPageButton: appTextBox.get('mainPageButton'),
  restartButton: appTextBox.get('restartButton'),
  backButton: appTextBox.get('backButton'),
  profileTitle: appTextBox.get('profileTitle'),
  loadingPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageSubtitle'),
  loadingPageBottomText: appTextBox.get('loadingPageBottomText'),
  loadingPageTitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageTitle'),
  profileButton: appTextBox.get('profileButton'),
  resultRestart: appTextBox.get('resultRestart'),
  resultTitle: appTextBox.get('resultTitle'),
  resultSwipe: appTextBox.get('resultSwipe'),
  secondaryTitle: appTextBox.get('secondaryTitle'),
  tretiaryProductTitle: appTextBox.get('tertiaryTitle'),
);
return appText;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
static Future<AppStrings> getAppText(String local) async {

var appTextBox = await Hive.openBox("appTextBox");

AppStrings? appText = new AppStrings(
  mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle'),
  timeText: appTextBox.get('timeText'),
  minutesText: appTextBox.get('minutesText'),
  mainPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageSubtitle'),
  mainPageParagraph: appTextBox.get('mainPageParagraph'),
  mainPageButton: appTextBox.get('mainPageButton'),
  restartButton: appTextBox.get('restartButton'),
  backButton: appTextBox.get('backButton'),
  profileTitle: appTextBox.get('profileTitle'),
  loadingPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageSubtitle'),
  loadingPageBottomText: appTextBox.get('loadingPageBottomText'),
  loadingPageTitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageTitle'),
  profileButton: appTextBox.get('profileButton'),
  resultRestart: appTextBox.get('resultRestart'),
  resultTitle: appTextBox.get('resultTitle'),
  resultSwipe: appTextBox.get('resultSwipe'),
  secondaryTitle: appTextBox.get('secondaryTitle'),
  tretiaryProductTitle: appTextBox.get('tertiaryTitle'),
);
if (appText !=null) {
  return appText;
}else{
  return null;
}
}
```

if you don't want to return null then return empty string in above code

Comment: Tried adding provided code but it is throwing error on return statement

return null;


A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'getAppText' because it has a return type of 'Future<AppStrings>'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type

Comment: if you need to return null ,update your return type like this Future<AppStrings?>  add this "?"

Comment: Still flutter run is failing with same error

     ` mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle'),`